# iframe gets deleted in Joomla JCE Editor

Tags: jce

Whenever I put Google's iFrame code in JCE editor and save it, the entire code will disappear. I already made sure that JCE doesn't block it in plugin manager and also through system global configuration.

I'm trying to paste the code under Chronoforms in the same article which probably doesn't give conflicts or somesort.

Anybody any ideas?
I don't want to use other editors. Also there seems no plugin like it needed for joomla 1.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try following:

**Check that the Editor Profile Parameters allow IFrames**

- In the JCE Control Panel, click on the Editor Profiles button.
- Click on the Profile name that the user, usergroup or component is assigned to, eg: 'Default'
- Click on the Plugin Parameters tab, then on the Media Support tab.
- Check that the Allow IFrames is set to Yes.

**Configure Joomla! Article filters**

- By default Joomla!  'cleans' content on saving, removing script tags,
  event attributes (such as onclick, onmouseover etc.) and style tags.
- A simple article parameter change is all that is required to fix
  this.

**Joomla 1.5**

See this article http://docs.joomla.org/Why_does_some_HTML_get_removed_from_articles_in_version_1.5.8%3F

**Joomla! 2.5 and Joomla! 3**

1. In the Joomla! Global Configuration, click on the Text Filters tab.
2. For the Super Users group, or any other trusted user group, set Filter Type to No Filtering. Make sure that you only set this option for user groups that can be trusted as setting the Filter Type to No Filtering will essentially allow the user to include any html in an article.

Addionally you can install iframe plugin to enable iFrame support:
https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/faq/category/iframe-plugin

Comment: Check that the Allow IFrames is set to Yes. Did it for me. To get there you can click on all the categories on the leftside of page which I didn't knew. haha. Thanks!