# Editor stripping iframe

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor, tinymce

Yes, another question about the stripping of HTML tags (this time TinyMCE).

Joomla 3.4.1 / TinyMCE 4.1.7

This should be very simple, however due to the number of comments and questions/answers I see already presumably I'm not the only one facing this issue. [There's a similar question here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1105/jce-tinymce-keeps-attempting-to-fix-valid-invalid-html) however I don't think the accepted answer is a resolution (very good work around though).

My issue though is only with iframes. The process is as follows;

I copy some youtube embed code > paste it into TinyMCE editor > it appears like this;

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qjnc0H8utks" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I immediatley click `toggle editor` > it appears like this;

```
<p>&lt;iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qjnc0H8utks" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;</p>
```

Things I have tried so far;

- removed `iframe` from TinyMCE `prohibited elements` in plugin settings
- set `no filtering` for super user in global settings
- Pasted the following code in TinyMCE `Extended Valid Elements`

  `iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder]`
- cleared joomla cache
- cleared browser cache
- tried various browsers
- tried various templates

The iframe works when using no editor or CodeMirror however they aren't options, I have to use TinyMCE on this occasion.

Any ideas what's going on? I'm lost!

Comment: On a side note please read this, as it's important: http://meta.joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/242/important-notice-for-joomla-3-4-4

Comment: Thanks @Lodder I plan on doing that before going live again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but you say:

> I copy some youtube embed code > paste it into TinyMCE editor > it appears like this

and

> I immediately click toggle editor > it appears like this;

Please note that if you paste HTML code in the regular TinyMCE window, it will be converted to HTML entities (`<` becomes `&lt;`, `>` becomes `&gt;` and so on).

**You have to do it the other way around**: First click <kbd>Toggle editor</kbd>, then paste your code, and toggle editor again. This is when TinyMCE will clean up your code if needed, and in your case remove the `<iframe>` element for two reasons:

1. Because by default, `iframe` is listed as **Forbidden element** in the plugin settings (as you mentioned).
2. Because **empty tags** are removed by default (there's no content between the opening `<iframe>` tag and the closing `</iframe>`. This is of course correct for iframes, but to TinyMCE it's just an empty tag, thus not needed.

I did a quick test, and with the following settings in the TinyMCE plugin settings it should work:

1. Remove `iframe` from the list of prohibited elements
2. Add `iframe[*]` to the "Extended Valid Elements" list:

[image: TinyMCE settings to allow iframes]

Save and close. Now edit your article, click the "Toggle editor" button, and paste your code. After clicking "Toggle editor" again, you should see something like this:

[image: Working iframe in TinyMCE]

Save your article, click "Toggle Editor" again, and verify that your iframe code is still intact.

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks @johanpw I was doing it the other way round (I was toggling the editor after pasting) - feel very silly! I suppose I expected the editor to be more intuitive. Well spotted and thank you :)

Comment: I have the same problem. it works as u said. but after saving, Iframe tag gets cut out again

Comment: Wish there was a way just to do this normally but it puts quotes around it and it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I had a lot of trouble with this until I realised you have to select the correct TinyMCE panel set before editing the Prohibited elements. Choose the set that is assigned to `administrator` and `editor`.

[[image: 1]]